# 2009 Honda Pilot 4WD

Tags: electrical, honda, battery-drain, pilot

I replaced a 7 year old battery 3 days ago. The solenoid was clicking so I figured it was the battery. The old battery had  an 11.5 amp draw . The new battery just went out again  today and solenoid is clicking again . The alternator was replaced a year ago. The drivers side air is blowing warm . The other zones including the rear and passenger compartments are cold . There seemed to be a puff of white smoke ( no odour) that emitted from the drivers side hood compartment. Any ideas thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. A 11.5Amp draw?? When the vehicle's at rest (engine not running, nothing on, not trying to start it)? It should be in the low milliamp draw area. That's a huge draw on a battery which shouldn't be getting used for anything.

Answer (score 2):

If your old battery had an 11.5 amp draw, it wasn't the battery's fault. Something in the car is on and draining power. Perform the battery draw test again and start pulling fuses one at a time until the draw disappears. That last fuse you pulled is telling you which electrical system is drawing power. Investigate from there.

If I were to guess:

- dome light is on
- parking lights are on
- something is plugged into the 12V outlet
- your seat warmers or AC outlets are clicked on